# What is the meaning of "*((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + 2;"

Tags: c

I am reading the source code of [berkeley-abc](https://github.com/berkeley-abc/abc). There is one code snippet, which is the following.

```
char *Aig_MmFixedEntryFetch(Aig_MmFixed_t *p)
{
  char *pTemp;
  int i;
  // check if there are still free entries
  if (p->nEntriesUsed == p->nEntriesAlloc)
  { // need to allocate more entries
    assert(p->pEntriesFree == NULL);
    if (p->nChunks == p->nChunksAlloc)
    {
        p->nChunksAlloc *= 2;
        p->pChunks = ABC_REALLOC(char *, p->pChunks, p->nChunksAlloc);
    }
    p->pEntriesFree = ABC_ALLOC(char, p->nEntrySize * p->nChunkSize);
    p->nMemoryAlloc += p->nEntrySize * p->nChunkSize;
    // transform these entries into a linked list
    pTemp = p->pEntriesFree;
    for (i = 1; i < p->nChunkSize; i++)
    {
        *((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize;
        pTemp += p->nEntrySize;
    }
    // set the last link
    *((char **)pTemp) = NULL;
    // add the chunk to the chunk storage
    p->pChunks[p->nChunks++] = p->pEntriesFree;
    // add to the number of entries allocated
    p->nEntriesAlloc += p->nChunkSize;
  }
  // incrememt the counter of used entries
  p->nEntriesUsed++;
  if (p->nEntriesMax < p->nEntriesUsed)
    p->nEntriesMax = p->nEntriesUsed;
  // return the first entry in the free entry list
  pTemp = p->pEntriesFree;
  p->pEntriesFree = *((char **)pTemp);
  return pTemp;
}
```

I can not understand what happened when executing "*((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize".

So I write a example like that, which is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char* pTemp = "aaaaaaaaaa";
  printf("%s 1\n", pTemp);
  *((char**)pTemp) = pTemp+2;
  printf("%s 2\n", pTemp);
  return 0;
}
```

The example can be compiled to one executable file, there is no error. However, when executing this executable file, there is segmentation fault, the executing result is as following.

```
aaaaaaaaaa 1
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This is really C code, not C++. In C++ it's just Undefined Behavior

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, their corresponding code snippet is "((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize;", theirs and mine are the same.

Comment: `void` came later in the C language than `char`, so for a while it was used as we now use `void*` to refer to "a pointer to arbitrary data". Try imagining is as if was "void*" - they are allocating a chunk of memory, putting it into a pointer and then using it to implement a basic list.

Comment: Also as @MSalters said, this is C not C++, in C++ this would be extremely unsound.

Comment: @ming li At the first glass it seems that who wrote this code is a very low qualified programmer.:)

Comment: @mcilloni, now I use gcc to compile my example, there is still segement fault. Can you help me to modify this example according to you thought?

Comment: @mingli I don't get why you would do that. I think your example completely fails to understand what is being done in the snippet you posted from the library. Those `char*` pointers do not point to actual strings, they are being used to hold arbitrary pointers which are then used to implement a list. For instance, `p->pEntriesFree` and thus `pTemp` point to allocated memory, which is then used to store pointers in order to create a sort of linked list. You can't print it with printf, and you can't use a random char array like "aaaa".

Comment: @mcilloni, I can understand your meaning. There are two adjacent program statements, which are "*((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize;" and "pTemp += p->nEntrySize;". According to my present knowledge, I think that they are the same. However, there should be different  meaning for these two statements, otherwise, only one sentence will be present in the code snippet. I want to find one small example to find what is the difference between them.

Comment: Anyone knows the difference between "*((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize;" and "pTemp += p->nEntrySize;"?

Comment: @mingli They are not the same. The first reinterprets the address contained in `pTemp` as a pointer of pointers, and then sets in the first element the value of the address of the third pointer of the list (which is pTemp + 3). The second moves pTemp ahead of `nEntrySize` positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And why not `*pTemp = pTemp + ...` ?

I don't want to critizice the code, but that cast `(char **)` and the naked address approach seem a bit...creative.

With a slightly different concept this can be done cleaner. Instead of a pointer to byte (char), I have pointer to address (to void). One indirection more, but no fake basic type (`void *` instead of `char` (no star)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    void **vpa = malloc(4096);    // arr. of ptrs (to void) 
    void **currp = vpa;

    int skip_elem = 5;            //  5 * sizeof *vpa -> 5*8 bytes entry size


    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        *currp = currp + skip_elem;
        currp += skip_elem;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
      printf("%p %p\n", vpa+i, vpa[i]);

    free(vpa);
}
```

Output is seven blocks filled like this:

```
0x55f9dc7922a0 0x55f9dc7922c8
0x55f9dc7922a8 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922b0 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922b8 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922c0 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922c8 0x55f9dc7922f0
0x55f9dc7922d0 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922d8 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922e0 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922e8 (nil)
0x55f9dc7922f0 0x55f9dc792318
0x55f9dc7922f8 (nil)
0x55f9dc792300 (nil)
0x55f9dc792308 (nil)
0x55f9dc792310 (nil)
0x55f9dc792318 0x55f9dc792340
...
```

With `char **` I get compiler warning about `char *` having a `char **` assigned (in `*currp =` ).

Answer (score 0):

`*((char **)pTemp) = pTemp + p->nEntrySize;` says to put the address that is `p->nEntrySize` bytes beyond `pTemp` into a `char *` located at `pTemp`.

`pTemp` points to some memory that is being organized into some number of “entries.” The code is making it into a linked list by putting a pointer (a `char *`) at the beginning of each entry that points to the next entry.

Given the pointer `pTemp` that points to the current entry and an entry size of `p->nEntrySize` bytes, `pTemp + p->nEntrySize` is the address of the next entry. Then `(char **)pTemp` converts the `char *` `pTemp` to a `char **`, a pointer to a `char *`. So the assignment says “Put the address computed for `pTemp + p->nEntrySize` at the address pointed to by `pTemp`.

This is different from `pTemp += p->nEntrySize;`, which says to change `pTemp`, rather than to change the memory `pTemp` points to.